# Prime numbers distribution theorem

Tags: prime-numbers, computational-mathematics

I'm trying to understand [Gauss' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem):
$$
    \frac{\pi(x) }{x/\ln x} \to 1
$$
for large $x$.

I've taken the list of first 1000 prime numbers from [Utah university site](http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/primelist.html), saved them to file

```
2
3
5
7
...
```

and plotted these values against their corresponding line numbers:

```
x | y
--+--
2 | 1
3 | 2
5 | 3
7 | 4
...
```

If I understand correctly $y(x)$ is the same as the prime-counting function $\pi(x)$, except that $y(x)$ is not defined for composite or non-integer $x$.

I used gnuplot to draw the graph:

```
gnuplot> plot '1000primes.txt' using 1:($0+1)
```

In `1:($0+1)` the first `1` stands for the first column in file for the `x`-points and `$0+1` means line number+1 as the `y`-points (counting of line numbers starts from 0). This way the first data point was at `(2,1)`.

From the theorem I'd expect this graph to merge with $x/\ln(x)$ for large $x$, but it wouldn't - it would pass above $x/\ln(x)$, though resembling it in shape. So I thought to multiply by a constant:

```
gnuplot> f(x) = a*x/log(x)
```

Using gnuplot's `fit` command I found the best-matching value for `a=1.13926`:

```
gnuplot> fit f(x) '1000primes.txt' using 1:($0+1) via a
```

So that the asymptotic relation is
$$
\pi(x) \to 1.13926... \times \frac{x}{\ln(x)}
$$

The resulting graph:

```
gnuplot> plot '1000primes.txt' using 1:($0+1), x/log(x), f(x)
```

[image: My plot]

What am I understanding/doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are simply underestimating the expression "the function is near the limit value *for large enough* x"

Comment: @AloizioMacedo so I should take a longer list? How long you think would be good enough?

Comment: See this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Prime_number_theorem_ratio_convergence.svg

Comment: @AloizioMacedo seems like this is correct, I've used about 80k primes and found that while the curves still don't merge, the best-fit coefficient `a` dropped to 1.08756. You should probably post this as an answer, so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the case here is that the convergence is very slow, and it may have misled you... for instance, see:
[this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Prime_number_theorem_ratio_convergence.svg)

Just for the record, there are functions that converge more quickly (one example being the one in the lower part of the above image).